# In a Django serializer, take default field value from context (or request data)

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django with the REST Framework. In a serializer, I would like to assign a field value based on a view or request (`request.data['type']`) parameter, so I need the view/request in the context.

I succeeded, but only in a cumbersome way, and I am looking into ways to simplify the code. Here's the successful approach (omitting irrelevant fields):

```
class TypeDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        view = serializer_field.context['view'] # or context['request']

        self.type = view.kwargs['type'].upper()

    def __call__(self):
        return self.type


class RRsetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(TypeDefault()))

    class Meta:
        model = RRset
        fields = ('type',)
        read_only_fields = ('type',)
```

To simplify things, I tried removing the `TypeDefault` class, and replacing the `type` serializer field by

```
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return self.context.get('view').kwargs['type'].upper() # also tried self._context
```

However, `context.get('view')` returns `None`. I am unsure why the view context is not available here. My impression is that it should be possible to get the desired functionality without resorting to an extra class.

As a bonus, it would be nice to specify the default in the field declaration itself, like

```
    type = serializers.CharField(default=self.context.get('view').kwargs['type'].upper())
```

However, `self` is not defined here, and I'm not sure what the right approach would be.

---

Also, I am interested if there is any difference in retrieving information from the view or from the request data. While the context approach should work for both, maybe there's a simpler way to get the `CreateOnlyDefault` functionality when the value is obtained from request data, as the serializers deals with the request data anyways.

---

**Edit:** Per Geotob's request, here is the code of the view that calls the serializer:

```
class RRsetsDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RRsetSerializer
    # permission_classes = ... # some permission constraints

    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.kwargs['name']
        type = self.kwargs.get('type')

        # Note in the following that the RRset model has a `domain` foreign-key field which is referenced here. It is irrelevant for the current problem though.
        if type is not None:
            return RRset.objects.filter(domain__name=name, domain__owner=self.request.user.pk, type=type)
        else:
            return RRset.objects.filter(domain__name=name, domain__owner=self.request.user.pk)
```

In `urls.py`, I have (among others):

```
url(r'^domains/(?P<name>[a-zA-Z\.\-_0-9]+)/rrsets/$', RRsetsDetail.as_view(), name='rrsets'),
url(r'^domains/(?P<name>[a-zA-Z\.\-_0-9]+)/rrsets/(?P<type>[A-Z]+)/$', RRsetsDetail.as_view(), name='rrsets-type'),
```

Comment: Can you add code samples for the view that calls the serializer?

Comment: @Geotob I did as requested. Let me know if I can be more explicit!

Comment: I was almost hoping that you weren't using a generic API view, because that would have been the obvious problem. :)

Comment: Your use of `SerializerMethodField` is the correct way here. `self.context` should hold keys for `view`, `request` and `format` if you're using one of DRF's generic views (which you are). This definitely works for me, so maybe a typo somewhere when you were testing it out?

Comment: @Geotob The first approach that I posted is indeed working (so, no typo). My question was about how to simplify / shorten the code, because it seems adding the TypeDefault class with two extra methods seems a lot of code for this standard problem. I wondered if I was missing the compact Django way of doing it.

Comment: I meant the second approach, where you use `SerializerMethodField` ;-) I'll add an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) is a read-only field so I do not think it will work unless you set a default value... and you are back to the same problem as with `CharField`.

To simply things you could get rid of `serializers.CreateOnlyDefault`:

```
class RRsetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, default=TypeDefault())
```

If you want something more dynamic, I can only think of something like this:

```
class FromContext(object):
    def __init__(self, value_fn):
        self.value_fn = value_fn

    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.value = self.value_fn(serializer_field.context)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.value


class RRsetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True,
            default=FromContext(lambda context: context.get('view').kwargs['type'].upper()))
```

`FromContext` takes a function during instantiation that will be used to retrieve the value you want from context.

Comment: I realized that when I do this, the model field constraints (e.g. max_length) are no longer honored. Do you have a suggestion how to achieve that as well?

Comment: I found the solution to my previous comment: call `self.clean_fields()` in the `save()` method of the model.

Answer (score 1):

All in all, your second approach above is the correct one:

Use `serializers.SerializerMethodField` and access `self.context` from the serializer method:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return self.context['view'].kwargs['type'].upper()
```

The `view`, `request` and `format` keys are automatically added to your serializer context by all of the DRF generic views (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods at the end of the section). This works just fine.

If you are creating a serializer instance manually, you will have to pass `context=contextDict` as an argument, where `contextDict` is whatever you need it to be (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).

As @Michael has pointed out in another answer, the `SerializerMethodField` will be read only. But going by your first example (`type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True.....`) this seems to be what you want.

Comment: Indeed `read_only` is set, but also `default` to set the value regardless of what is sent in the request as described in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#advanced-field-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Migth be in newer version, but you can now do the class default using the context, see [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#default)

```
class CurrentUserDefault:
"""
May be applied as a `default=...` value on a serializer field.
Returns the current user.
"""
requires_context = True

def __call__(self, serializer_field):
    return serializer_field.context['request'].user
```